# Can I instrument outgoing method/constructor calls with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, profiling, javassist, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy

I have a project where I was using Javassist to log outgoing method/constructor calls with code like this:

```
CtMethod cm = ... ;
cm.instrument(
new ExprEditor() {
    public void edit(MethodCall m)
                  throws CannotCompileException
    {
        if (m.getClassName().equals("Point")
                      && m.getMethodName().equals("move"))
            m.replace("{ $1 = 0; $_ = $proceed($$); }");
    }
});
```

which assigns '0' to the first argument of the called method and then proceeds with the original call, that is, if `cm` represents the method `someMethod` we modify the outgoing calls to `Point::move` from `someMethod`:

```
public int someMethod(int arg1){        
    Point p;
    ...
    Point newPoint =
    //Here we start tampering with the code        
        p.move(0, arg2, arg3, arg4); //Say it was originally p.move(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    //From here we leave it as it was
    ...
}
```

I am now trying to migrate to **ByteBuddy** as I wanted the classes to be **compatible with (online) JaCoCo**. I've managed to instrument methods and constructors "from the inside" (instrumenting the called methods themselves), but I haven't found any way to do it "from the outside" (instrumenting the calls to such methods from elsewhere). Is there any way to do it with ByteBuddy ?

This question is related to [another which asked for a way to catch constructor exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248429/how-to-take-the-exception-thrown-by-a-constructor-using-a-bytebuddy-agent) as it is the way I achieved it using Javassist.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an argument of a method by using `Advice` which allows you to change an argument prior to the original method's execution:

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
static void enter(@Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) int arg) {
  arg = 0;
}
```

Doing so, the above code will be prepended to the `move` method that you need to locate using an `ElementMatcher` like `named("move")`.

Comment: Instead of the arguments, is there a way to change the body of the method? Specifically, I want to look for a specific library call (like `ArrayList.add()`) being present inside the method and want to add a line of code before it.

Comment: You can replace the method and the substitution API is rather extensible if you want to add your own byte code. A simpler DSL is still in the making.

Comment: I have a more detailed query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584788/byte-buddy-member-substitution-throwing-illegalstateexception-error). please consider helping me out!